# start service at a particular time depending on the system clock

Tags: android

I have the following code in my **UpdateService.java**:

```
package com.missnoob.screentimeout;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UpdateService extends Service {
    Timer timer;
    Toast toast;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // REGISTER RECEIVER THAT HANDLES SCREEN ON AND SCREEN OFF LOGIC
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
    if (!screenOn) {
        Log.v("ScreenTimeOut","Broadcast Received");
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

I want to start the service at a particular time only

**e.g.** I want the service to be active during 7 PM to 12 PM.
How can I implement such thing.

Comment: Have you seen this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689330/wake-app-up-from-sleep-at-set-time

Comment: @RameshPrasad I have seen it but it is not what I am searching for.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set two alarm event for this from which first will raise in start time and another will raise on end time.