# Android Development, RTC_WAKEUP

Tags: android

I’m new to Android development so the most basic of explanations would be helpful. I have developed a simple checklist app for work which consists of 4 checklists eg morning, afternoon and so on. Once completed the lists are emailed to the owner, the problem is I would like to send an sms alert if each list isn’t completed by a certain time eg evening list before 9pm. My method is to use a simple shared preferences file to advance the count from 0 to 1 when the checklist is sent but then at the preset time have it check the count and either send an sms or reset the count to zero. I have everything worked out except for the timer, I understand that I need to use RTC_WAKEUP to achieve my goal but this is where I’m stuck, I have failed to find a suitably straight forward explanation on how to get the app to wake up at a set time and check the count. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the question in this one-paragraph book?

Comment: I’m sorry if my question offended your grammatical sensibilities but I was just trying explain my problem as precisely as I could. I’ll try harder to live up to your standards in future but at the moment this is all I have. The questions is how do I use RTC_WAKEUP, the remainder of the book was an attempt to explain the exact situation where I would implement it thereby narrowing down to what extent I need it explained.

Comment: I didn't want to be rude, sorry. Maybe your post would be more attractive with paragraphs and blank lines. This may help: [Wake up app from sleep at set time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689330/wake-up-app-from-sleep-at-set-time).